# gnome 3 sound volume applet + hotkeys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, gnome, hotkeys

I have installed today gnome 3 (debian wheezy). when I use hotkeys to change sound volume ugly applet window appears

[image: volume applet]

my computer slows down while this applet renders. 1 frame per second. geforce 8500 + nvidia proprietary drivers installed properly

How can I disable this applet or make it smaller? I want to use sound volume hotkeys without this ugly window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug between nvidia and xorg.

Upgrade (or downgrande) your nVidia driver from Experimental to fix this issue.

Comment: (facepalm)
I have succesfully leaved to xfce

Comment: I would've said to switch, why use gnome in the first place?

Comment: because I am always use linux for work. xfce is ideal for me. I have no touch phones to use gnome 3 on it. this is obvious that gnome 3 is no way to work